# Binding ListBoxItem properties when ListBox is bound to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionOfFoos}" />
```

The ObservableCollection contains instances of Foo, Foo implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
I'm trying to bind properties of the ListBoxItems to properties of Foo.
Here is what I tried:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo}" >
    <TextBlock Content="{Binding PropertyOfFoo}" Background="{Binding AnotherPropertyOfFoo}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

this works, but, the problem is that I only have access to the properties of the TextBlock and not the containing ListBoxItem, so, for example, Background only changes the color around the text and not the whole entry. I have a feeling I'm using the wrong tool for the job here.

a point in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` specifies the template (UI presentation) of the content of the list box item. What you need to style is the item container itself which can be done via the `ItemContainerStyle` property of the `ListBox`.